# Почему overflow-y: hidden добавляет горизонтальный скролл?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Почему `overflow-y: hidden`, при условии что контент превышает ширину, добавляет горизонтальный скролл? И возможно ли от него избавится без `overflow-x:hidden`?

```css
.parent{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border:1px solid;
  
  overflow-y:hidden;
  
}

.child{
  width:110px;
  height:200px;
  
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет не возможно...

Comment: ты лучше опиши в вопросе, что именно ты хочешь слелать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties)

> Значение: как указано, за одним исключением, `visible` меняется на `auto`, если у одного из свойств `overflow-x` или `overflow-y` значение не `visible`.

следовательно код в примере аналогичен

```
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:auto;
```

И так как ширина дочернего элемента больше контейнера, появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

Следовательно для решения нужно явно задать `overflow-x:hidden;`

Answer (score -2):

Не знаю,что ты пытаешься сделать, но может быть вот это.

```
.parent{
        width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        border:1px solid;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y:visible;
 }
```

Comment: Либо просто overflow:hidden; , в зависимости от нужного результата.